# trouble installing matplotlib python? WINDOWS

Tags: python, windows

So I used pip to install matplotlib module through command line in windows, but when I then try to import the module in python, it says no module is found.

How do I fix this?
When I've tried to install it again, it says the module exists and can be found through my files. However python doesn't seem to be able to link to it to import it?

Comment: Please expand your question, what result are you expecting? Have you debugged the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Python 2.7, you will want to read the following document at it details how to install MySQLdb1 on the various platforms:

- https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1

See the INSTALL file specifically.

Note that this is kind of a legacy module. If you want something that works in Python 3, you might want to check out [moist](https://github.com/farcepest/moist).

There is also [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/), which is compatible with both Python 2.6+ and 3.3+ and it can be installed with pip:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

Comment: pip is a program used for installing most Python packages and comes with Python 3 now. You can read about it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip or here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/